# How to create a drawable xml from this PNG image?

Tags: android, resources, png, drawable, android-drawable

[image: blue back ground with white stripe]

I have this PNG image above (which I exported from Figma). How do I recreate it using drawable xml?
I want to try using layer-list but I'm not sure how to do it.
I need to use drawable because I need to set custom color to it.

Here is my drawable code:

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_color"/>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- I'm suppose I need to add some code here but I'm not sure what it is -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

background_color.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/primary"
        android:startColor="@color/secondary" />
</shape>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#001A6E</color>
    <color name="secondary">#0070C0</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

Is there any other better way to recreate this PNG image?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps....Im not using the exported image here, as i got the gradient colors from your resources.

You can adjust the `bottomLeftRadius` or `bottomRightRadius` as per your needs. its high level solution for such purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#001A6E"
        android:startColor="#0070C0" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you can create three different drawable xml files to achieve what you want. I have also used your color resource.

image.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
         android:drawable="#001A6E"/>
      <item>
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
```

image_background_white.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item
            android:drawable="#ffffff"/>
         <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            </shape>
         <item>
      </layer-list>
```

image_with_roundcorner.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <gradient
     android:angle="90"
     android:endColor="#001A6E"
     android:startColor="#0070C0" />

 <corners
     android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
     android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Use the above three drawable in your main xml like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_background_white" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_with_roundcorner" />

</LinearLayout>
```